# How to go about making a two-stage FAT32 USB bootloader?

Tags: assembly, usb, bootloader, osdev, fat32

I'm making my own OS and I've read everything there is to read about homemade OSdev. However, I do not understand how to make a two-stage bootloader. More specifically, I can't understand how to get my first stage to locate the second stage on the FAT32 filesystem.

DIAGRAM: first stage -> second stage (enable pmode, gdt, etc) -> kernel

USB Specs:

- 4 GB, 3.75 GB usable

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 2):

I myself am working on a self-written OS two (over one year now). I have written a two-stage boot loader for FAT12/16 and FAT32 and there is a significant difference:

- On FAT12/16 it is quite easy to write a boot loader
- On FAT32 it is very difficult because a lot of things that are located in the first sector of the second stage in the FAT12/16 loader must already be in the boot sector for FAT32.

As far as I know even Windows either insists that the stage two file is one of the first files on the root directory (in this case less code in the boot sector is required) or some extra sectors with fixed sector numbers are used to "extend" the boot sector to a size > 512 bytes.

For an own operating system that should co-exist with other systems on the same disk both approaches won't work.

My boot loader works the following way:

It calculates the sector number of the first cluster. It contains a sub-routine that can read a sector by a given cluster number (they are 32-bit!) and a cluster-relative sector.

The first sector of the root directory (the cluster number is known) is read and searched for the file containing the stage two code. Then the second sector is read and so on.

When all sectors of a cluster are read then the FAT must be read to get the cluster number of the next cluster of the root directory. This is the part that is in the stage two code for FAT12/16 boot loaders but must be located in the boot sector itself for FAT32 boot loaders.

As soon as the directory entry is found you'll load the first sector of the first cluster of the stage two file. Loading the rest of the file can be done by code in the first sector of the stage two file!

When using INT 13h, function 42h (linear disk read supported by BIOSs newer than 1995) the 512 bytes of the boot sector are just enough if you use very short error messages only. Using INT 13h, function 2 (C/H/S disk read) I didn't manage to write a FAT32 boot sector because 512 bytes are just not enough.

Comment: 512 bytes should be plenty enough for the first stage, you don't even need to particularly optimize for size. Otherwise, yeah, that's how I did it too.

Comment: @Jester - You forget about the file system: FAT32. Unlike EXT2 the file system meta information is stored in the first sector so you have only about 430 bytes left for code. "Stage two" is stored in a file which means that you have to parse the entire root directory using the code in the boot sector. This is why Microsoft uses an additional sector - in GRUB this would be called stage 1.5 - or assumes that their file is one of the first files in the root directory.

Comment: LOL I didn't forget, you don't have to explain it to me. It's trivial to parse the root directory.

Comment: @Jester is your OS open source?

Comment: I don't have much of an OS, I just helped somebody :) But [here is the relevant part from the boot sector](http://pastebin.com/gi3uhyYK) (179 bytes). Scanning a directory block for a file name and walking a simple 32 bit fat chain isn't very hard.

Comment: @Jester - The code in the link seems to be incomplete (ebp is not initialized!) and seems only to work with a cluster size of 1 sector but the default under Windows 9x is 8 sectors. This code uses 80386 instructions. My one is using 8086 instructions only - was some of my internal requirements. 32-bit arithmetic with 16-bit registers only will make the code much longer!

Comment: 16 bit arithmetic won't make it much longer (keep in mind that 32 bit instructions need a prefix and possibly a SIB byte too), but it would make it harder to write. The OS will need 32 bit cpu anyway. You are right about the cluster size, but that's easy to add.

Comment: @Jester "easy to add" is not the point. The point is that all of these things require memory: Just the test if the kernel.bin file is correct (magic number OK, not a directory...) is additonal 29 bytes in my boot sector; Support for different cluster sizes would be about 28 bytes; printing a message on errors is 49 bytes and so on. Summing all this up the 179 bytes will soon end in 512 bytes. 8086 code was a requirement because I'm interested in retrocomputing and the boot menu is able to work on an IBM XT (8088 CPU) because it even adds new features to MS-DOS!

Comment: Just because you might have special requirements, you can't say "512 bytes is not enough".  I have showed it is possible. Yeah, if you stick in verbose error messages and other cruft, then it might not be enough.

Comment: Please read my answer carefully: I said that writing a boot loader that does NOT HAVE any requirements on the location of the file using CHS addressing is nearly impossible (I already tried using 32-bit code which was only little improvement). Similar to the Windows boot loader the 179 byte bootloader (the 179 bytes are not the complete boot loader but some parts are missing) only works if the directory entry of "kernel.bin" is located in the first sector of a cluster - which won't work when installing the OS on a non-empty disk.

Comment: You are nitpicking. Rest assured, I have already updated the code to be pure 16 bit AND scan all the sectors in a cluster and it still has plenty of free space for your error messages and crc ...

Comment: If you managed this it is great. I didn't think that it would be possible!

Comment: Had a little time to debug it, so [here it is](http://pastebin.com/34gFXy38). It works for FAT12/16/32 from floppy or hd and has 86 bytes left for error messages and crc. On second thought, long file name entries should be filtered out to avoid a false file match.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to write your own bootloader?

There are already plenty of x86 bootloaders available (Lilo, Grub, and Extlinux among others). They are not specific to Linux; so long as your OS conforms to [the multiboot specification](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html), any of them will be able to boot your OS. Using any one of them will save you a lot of development time.

That all being said, the most common approaches to locating the second-stage bootloader are to either:

1. Store it in the slack space after the MBR, before the first partition. (This assumes that such space exists, but it does on most disks.)

OR

2. Embed a list of sector numbers into the first-stage bootloader, directing it to where it will find the second-stage bootloader.

Comment: The thing is, I want to make my own bootloader because many of these other bootloaders have too many features. I like GRUB, but I don't really need modules, or multiboot functionality as yet. I'm not going to distribute this OS, it's just for private use.